# Ensuring Compliance: Connecting Salesforce and Third-Party Apps with Secure User Authentication

Tags: authentication, salesforce

I am trying to establish a connection between a Salesforce application and an external application, where the user's login credentials are entered on the third-party app instead of the Salesforce login page. The third-party app uses connected apps to authenticate the user and establish the connection, but this creates a compliance issue since the user's credentials are not entered on the Salesforce registry. I would like to avoid using a custom login page in the external app and instead use the standard Salesforce login page where the user can enter their credentials. Once the user is successfully authenticated on the Salesforce login page, I want the third-party app to establish a connection with Salesforce.